# ESP32 - Clock setting

Tags: clock, esp32, rtos

I've been trying to code a ESP32 device with esp-idf sdk (rtos programming).

Normally, in my personal projects, I'm used to bare metal programming, while at work, I handle linux systems. It seems to me that esp-idf is between them.

I'm kind of lost, because I would like to precisely set the CPU clock frequency. However, the only thing I found in the sdk, regarding clock, is the power management unit being capable of change it dynamically.

Is there a way to set esp32 cpu clock frequency with a fixed value, or do I have to bear in mind that the rtos abstracts this control level?

Comment: What's the bigger context? Why would you want to "precisely set the CPU clock frequency"?

Comment: Because it's what I'm used to in microelectronic systems. Perhaps, I'm interpreting the ESP32 in a wrong way.

Comment: The ESP32 is less open than other MCUs and has less low-level documentation. It's clearly meant to be used with the ESP-IDF framework. For clocks in particular, the framework has a higher level API and manages the details automatically - with all related pros and cons. You can fiddle with the low-level settings if you want (see https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf) but it will likely break several ESP-IDF components as they are no longer aware of the effective clock rate.